# Screens turn off and keep turning back on with mouse cursor and black screen (Ubuntu 18.10)

Tags: mouse, screen, 18.10, cursor, timeout

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.10 and only have one issue with screen inactivity.

After setting blank screen time (15min) my dual screens turn off for about 5 seconds and then turn back on with a black screen and the mouse cursor.

Its still responsive when I move the mouse.  It all goes back to normal as though the screens turned back on.

The screens do not stay off when the timeout is reached.  They only completely shut off for a few sec, and come back to the same black screen with mouse cursor.

Anyone with insight on this issue, please advise.

Thanks in advance.

AT